# How to genereate multi level (rows and columns) pivot table in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

I am trying to genereate data structured in below format. Is there some library that can help in generating below grouped data structure.

Note : The grouping level at rows and columns is dynamic. AccountingPeriod, Ledger, Cost_Center are table columns and Balance Amount is measure. In below snapshot, we are getting balance amount grouped by these 3 columns.

[pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BzFV.png)

Comment: The image you linked seems to be blank, is that intentional?

Comment: @Luctia i have updated the image link.

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question does not quite meet community guidelines - asking for libraries/tutorials is outside of the scope here. On this site it is very important, when asking a question, to show your work - what you have already tried. Please read [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**how to create a minimum, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better results when using the site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might want to save data in a CSV, XLSX, etc way. You can search for libraries that allow you to do that, for CSV formats take a look at [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). If you're aiming to find a library specialized for XLSX or another structure, you could search for something like `java xlsx library`.